# What's the deal with the C:\Program Files\xerox\nwwia folder?

Tags: windows-xp

It doesn't contain anything, can't be deleted. Seems to just hang there forever.

Does anyone here knows what its story?

Comment: This deserves a 'jerry-seinfeld' tag or something for the title. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently (from [this forum](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-nt-2000-xp/117570-xerox-nwwia.html?5d9d53121221f23a43677c678d1c60a3=)):

> Xp has inbuilt ability to scan and OCR docs.
>
> This ability was licenced from Xerox, despite the fact that every scanner uses it's own ocr program much better than XP built in generic hit or miss form
>
> If you are determined to use the inbuilt XP version, if your scanner will let you, it will use the Xerox/nwwia folder as tempory holding place for the files while it processes them.
>
> It is perfectly harmless so leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_program_filesxeroxnwwia_and_how_do_i_get_rid_of_it.html) it's a harmless "ghost" file.

Answer (score 0):

I read a post on [ask-leo.com](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_program_filesxeroxnwwia_and_how_do_i_get_rid_of_it.html) that basically said nobody knows why it is there, but may have something to do with "Windows Image Acquisition", and that it is the windows login process that has the directory open.  Also, it is safe.